# How can I wait until an S3 file is updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have a JVM web service, and I want to know when an S3 bucket is updated. I know s3 has event notifications, but from what I've read those are more like hooks that you can configure to send a message to a lambda function, for example.

Is there a way to do this from within an app? Something like `MyBucket.WaitUpdate().Then(...do something...)`. The alternative is to just poll periodically, but I'd rather be more responsive to changes.

Comment: What will be the source of change in the S3 bucket? Are you anticipating a human-driven change? Your application-level change?

Comment: How do you define "when an S3 bucket is updated"? Do you mean it should wait until an object is created or overwritten? Can you possibly tell us more about your situation -- that is, _why_ are you wanting to wait?

Comment: Human driven change; looking for an object change (overwrite). Basically I want to know when metadata changes, so that I can reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 can send event notification messages to the following destinations:

- Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) topics
- Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queues
- AWS Lambda function

In this way, for your case, we need to work in one of these destinations. (eg. send the notification for a SQS queue, and then pool in your application, or send a SNS notification and you want be more responsive to the changes like you said use the AWS Lambda service)